Mount CIFS volume on podman container with molecule/ansible. Error : Operation not permitted
I'm trying to mount a CIFS volume on a podman container with molecule and ansible without success.
Content of create.yml:
tasks:
    - name: Create a container
      containers.podman.podman_container:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        image: "{{ item.image }}"
        privileged: true
        volumes: "{{ item.volumes | default(omit) }}"
        capabilities: "{{ item.capabilities | default(omit) }}"
        systemd: "{{ item.systemd | default(omit) }}"
        security_opt: 
          - label=disable
          - seccomp=unconfined
        cap_add: 
          - "SYS_ADMIN" 
          - "DAC_READ_SEARCH"
        state: started
        command: "{{ item.command | default('sleep 1d') }}"
        # bash -c "while true; do sleep 10000; done"
        log_driver: json-file
      register: result
      loop: "{{ molecule_yml.platforms }}"

Contents of the task that mounts the CIFS volume:
- name: Mount temporary CIFS volume on datasave
  become: yes
  ansible.posix.mount:
    path: "/data/postgresql"
    src: "//xxxxx.xxxxx.xx/data"
    opts: "rw,credentials=/root/credential,uid=xxx,gid=xxx,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775"
    fstype: cifs
    state: mounted

I get this error:
"msg": "Error mounting /data/postgresql: mount error(1): Operation not permitted\nRefer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)\n"}

I tried to add these options to create.yml but it didn't work.
security_opt: 
          - label=disable
          - seccomp=unconfined
        cap_add: 
          - "SYS_ADMIN" 
          - "DAC_READ_SEARCH"
privileged: true


I suggest to 1) Make sure that mount task is executed towards Podman container that you created (using -vvvv might certain additional information). 2) Start a container where you have eg. Bash and try to use mount command inside the container.
